# active serviceWorker is not sending message to waiting serviceWorker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

**What am I trying to do?**

I am creating a progressive web application (PWA) and in order to send upgrade the app correctly, I am working on a step where the user is notified and once the user says "upgrade", the `serviceWorker` calls `skipWaiting()`

**What have I done so far?**
I am following up a nice article https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68 to achieve this

In order to remove the complexity, I am only testing sending of messages between `serviceWorkers` to see how `skipWaiting` works. I am using `create-react-app (v"react": "^16.5.2",)` which comes with `workbox` bundled as plugin.

My current `registerServiceWorker.js` looks like

```
// In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model, read 
// This link also includes instructions on opting out of this behavior.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (!isLocalhost) {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      } else {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') {
        console.log('skipWaiting');
        return navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(swUrl)
          .then(registration => registration.skipWaiting());
      }

      console.log(`message=${messageEvent.data}`);
    });

    let refreshingPage;
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
      console.log('refreshing page now');
      if (refreshingPage) return;
      refreshingPage = true;
      window.location.reload();
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('>> New content is available; please refresh.');
              navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('skipWaiting');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

As you see, when a new serviceWorker is `installed`, I am sending a `postMessage` as

```
console.log('>> New content is available; please refresh.');
navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('skipWaiting');
```

and I am expecting the message to be handled with the function

```
    window.addEventListener('message', messageEvent => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') {
        console.log('skipWaiting');
        return navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(swUrl)
          .then(registration => registration.skipWaiting());
      }

      console.log(`message=${messageEvent.data}`);
    });
```

Then, I deploy my changes so that this `serviceWorker` is ready. 
Then, I make changes to my application (`index.html`) and now when I deploy, I see multiple messages being logged, but none with `skipWaiting`

```
message=
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"h":"I0_1548194465894"}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"/I0_1548194465894::_g_rpcReady","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":1,"a":[null],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":null,"a":[1,[null]],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":null,"a":[2,[null]],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"/I0_1548194465894::_g_restyleMe","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":2,"a":[{"setHideOnLeave":false}],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":null,"a":[4,[null]],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"/I0_1548194465894::authEvent","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":3,"a":[{"type":"authEvent","authEvent":{"type":"unknown","eventId":null,"urlResponse":null,"sessionId":null,"postBody":null,"tenantId":null,"error":{"code":"auth/no-auth-event","message":"An internal error has occurred."}}}],"g":false}
registerServiceWorker.js:53 message=!_{"s":"__cb","f":"I0_1548194465894","r":"I0_1548194465894","t":"32296067","c":null,"a":[3,[true]],"g":false}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This code looks very confused. You've exhibited only one script here, `registerServiceWorker.js` that runs in the page, but service workers require at least two scripts, one running in the page, and one running in the service worker. I recommend learning this material by taking Google's Udacity course. https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899

Answer (score 0):

There a few things wrong

1. `navigator.serviceWorker.controller.postMessage('skipWaiting');`

This is sending a message from `window` to `worker`, but you're waiting for the message on the `window`

- controller -> is not the worker instance. `postMessage()` would send the message to that worker.
- You don't want to post to that worker though - it's your current active worker, while you want to notify the newly installed worker that haven't taken over yet

2. Even if you manage to run the code in the `message` event handler it won't do

```js
      if (messageEvent.data === 'skipWaiting') {
        console.log('skipWaiting');
        return navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration(swUrl)
          .then(registration => registration.skipWaiting());
      }
```

There's no `registration.skipWaiting()` method. We call `skipWaiting` inside the `service-worker.js` code

In your case you would add an event listener for `message` inside the worker code and intercept the "Skip Waiting" message there

#### worker code

```js
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data == 'skipWaiting') self.skipWaiting();
});
```

#### window code (changes only)

Send a message to the now installed worker to skip waiting and take over

```js
console.log('>> New content is available; please refresh.');
installingWorker.postMessage('skipWaiting');
```